# 400 Error when Cloud Code from Twilio

Tags: javascript, post, parse-platform, twilio, pubnub

We've configured our Twilio number to post to the following parse url but it's returning a 400 error: https://myAppId:javascript-key=myJSkey@api.parse.com/1/functions/sendMsgFromTwilio

The parse api says we need a content type header. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Here's our code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendMsgFromTwilio", function (req, res) {
  //use From phone number param to get client object
  ParseUtils.getUserAccount(Crypto.hash(req.params.From)).then(function(result) {

//get providerId from ProviderClient table
var clientId = result.id;
ParseUtils.getProviderClient(clientId).then(function(result) {
  var providerId = result.providerId;

  //make sure we're actually passing on a message
  if(req.params.Body.length > 0) {
    var messageType = 0; //text message type

    //prepare parameters in hash as done in sendMsg function
    var params = {
      params : {
        providerId: providerId,
        clientId: clientId,
        payload: {
          type: messageType,
          content: req.params.Body
        }
      }
    }

    //pass message to helper function to send to pubnub
    Messaging.sendMsgAsIs(params).then(function (result) {
      res.success(result);
    }, function (error) {
      res.error(error);
    });
  }
})
```

});
});

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Guillaume, what is the resulting PubNub URL? Be sure to not include your full sub/pub keys, but 400 error from PubNub could be "invalid subscribe key" error which could mean a typo in the sub-key, wrong sub-key, key has been disabled or possibly other things. Send full URL to support@pubnub.com if you believe this to be the root cause.

Comment: Hey Craig, it runs fine in curl so it's a twilio issue. Twilio says it needs to see XML but I don't see how that could return a 400. We're running a php script for now but would love to get to the root of this. :/

Comment: OK - if you suspect PubNub or that we can be of any assistance, just let us know.

Comment: Hey Craig, just got to the bottom of this with Twilio. Looks like they need to see some twiml (basically their version of xml) or it'll misinterpret and and fire off a HTTP read error. Unfortunately, we can't seem to throw any xml in our cloud code due to parse restrictions. :/ So php script it is for the time being. Let me know if you have any better suggestions?

Comment: So this is a Parse.com issue with not allowing XML? If so, do they have any input on this?

Comment: It's an issue on both sides. Would be great if Parse accepted XML, and would be great if Twilio didn't force a 404 when they don't see XML. No answers from either side.

Comment: OK, well let us know if you are assistance with this. We have a Parse SDK https://www.pubnub.com/docs/parse-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk and here is a PubNub Twillio tutorial: http://www.bold-it.com/php/twilio/get-the-picture-twilio-pubnub/

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to implement this is not as a cloud function, but as a custom endpoint.  On the hosted Parse solution, this is documented here: https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#hosting-dynamic-websites

Now with Parse Server, it would be just a standard express route alongside your server.  Find out more about Parse Server here: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/what-is-parse-server/